# Verify That Filters on a Dataset are Exclusive

Tags: data, validation, filtering

Suppose I have a data table of, say, cars with a bunch of properties for each record. Example:

|Vin|Year|Make|Model|Color|Mileage|

I want to allow users to define (arbitrarily complex) filters which can be used to return a subset of records from the table. However, there's a catch: each vehicle record can only appear in up to one subset. So for example, a user can add two filters:

(make = 'Chevrolet')
(make = 'Ford')

This is valid, because no vehicles will be duplicated between the two sets returned. However, suppose a user enters two different filters:

(make = 'Chevrolet')
(color = 'Black')

This is an invalid filter set, because any black Chevy will appear in both result sets.

It's also possible to nest and combine filter units into one single filter: e.g.

((make = 'Chevrolet') AND ((color = 'Black') OR (year >= 2012)))

which will return all Chevys with a black exterior, or a model year of 2012 or greater.

Without knowing anything about the actual data in the table, is there a way to validate whether a set of filters is guaranteed to be exclusive?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: You said  (make='chevrolet') (make='Ford') are two filters but ((make = 'Chevrolet') AND ((color = 'Black') OR (year >= 2012))) is also more than one filter? If everything has a set of parenthesis on the outside, it's one filter.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll clarify. What i mean is that a Filter (Filterset?) is a combination of one or more filter items.

Comment: Without knowing *anything* about the data, it seems like the only way to know that two filters are mutually exclusive is to see if there are any columns both of them refer to, which you seem to already be aware of. Is there something you want us to add to that?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to let the user know they need to filter even more when you get more than one result.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter functions with type information to do validation. For example, SPARQL uses the following syntax:

```
FILTER( (?open != 1) || (((NOW() - xsd:datetime(?DATA_S))
```

**References**

- [Making SPARQL Filter Conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717106/making-sparql-filter-conditional)
- [List of SPARQL Filter Functions](https://docs.data.world/tutorials/sparql/list-of-sparql-filter-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

General speaking, yes.  What you're describing is a query expression and the desire to evaluate on that expression.

I think a good means of depicting and representing the higher-order concept is by reviewing and evaluating LINQ\Lambda and `ExpressionTree` in .NET and\or Java.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an Abstract Standards or Specification to link to that isn't language specific, but you'll find general overviews on each platform's implementation.  There are quite a few draft discussions on Lamda Expressions for Java8 introduce as well.